# How to remove parenthesis value from a PickList field using formula field?

Tags: apex, visualforce, trigger, formula

I want to create a formula field which fetches value from picklist field and display the value excluding parenthesis value.

For Example:- I have a picklist field with value: "Data(Matched)"
          Expected Value to Display on formula field is "Data".

Need to remove value which exists inside bracket and display on formula field

Can anyone help me on this.

Comment: how many values are there in picklist? If it is not more then you can go for CASE().

Comment: We have 100+ values in picklist

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [string/text functions](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=customize_functions.htm#text_functions) **FIND** and **LEFT** to do this.

use **FIND** to get the index of the left parenthesis and pass that to the **LEFT** function to return the characters upto that position.

something like this

```
LEFT(YourPickListField, FIND("(", YourPickListField) -1)
```